# Open document in existing instance

Tags: java, windows, exec

How can I programmatically open a document in a non-default application, without launching a new instance of that application if one already runs?

Context: I want to programmatically launch images with Paint Shop Pro (or similar) but the default application is "Windows Photo Viewer", which I'm not going to change. When I launch multiple such images, they should all open in the same instance.

Futile attempt, opens new instance of PSP for every image:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"<path_to_psp.exe>", pathToImage.toString()});
```

- Windows 10, doesn't need to be portable
- This program is just something experimental for me, no need to consider other computers or set-ups.
- I'm versed with `JNA`, just not with MSDN stuff

Comment: Have you tried passing multiple image paths as arguments to psp?

Comment: That doesn't help when I later want to open another image in the same instance

Comment: As far as I know, the only entity that has control over this is psp itself and can only be controlled, if at all, in psp settings.

Comment: Then how do you explain that Windows is able to open images in the same PSP instance, if I set it as the default program?

Comment: When I make it default in windows, open multiple files in succession, and inspect the command line with Process Explorer, it's all just `psp.exe /dde` and nothing else! I suspect it's something akin to POST messages in html, as in, that there's data sent through another channel. What does this mean, and how can I do 'dde' in Java?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways applications can specify how they open file types they registered in the registry:

- The path on the command line
- DDE (Dynamic Data Exchange, a old way to communicate between applications using messages)
- [DropTarget](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100503-00/?p=14183)
- DelegateExecute

Paint Shop Pro (at least the old versions) use DDE and that is a lot of work to implement yourself. The best solution is to get Windows to invoke the handler for you.

One option is to see if the application shows up in [`SHAssocEnumHandlers`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-shassocenumhandlers), and if it does, call its `IAssocHandler::Invoke`.

If you know a little about the application (as you do in this case) you can use the old way of forcing a ProgId by calling `ShellExecuteEx` with `fMask` set to `SEE_MASK_CLASSNAME|SEE_MASK_FLAG_DDEWAIT` and [`lpClass` set to](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140210-00/?p=1823) "PSP7.Image" (or whatever version you care about). This works as long as the specified ProgId key has a working verb in its shell subkey.